# Ethereum data reading and writing time fluctuation for web3

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, blockchain, web3js

I have created a web app for sending and receiving data in ropsten testchain.
The average result of writing Data to the blockchain and reading it. The average is calculated for 5 transactions.

Here data input is an integer list.

Now the writing time and reading time varies as the size of array is changed.

**I want to know why the writing time is decreasing while increasing data volume. And also for the 60 input data takes more time to write. Similarly for reading time why the 120 input data is taking less time to read compared to the others. Can I know why the fluctuation of data reading and writing time?**

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|Data Input Per Minute|  Avg. Txn Writing|  Gas Cost(wei)   | Avg. Data Reading|
|    (Size of array)  |   Time (seconds) |                  |   Time (seconds) |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          6          |        24.2      |      236576      |       2.61       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |        19.6      |      359289      |       3.36       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          60         |        28.8      |      1340996     |       4.68       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         120         |        19.3      |      2568142     |       2.31       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         360         |        18.1      |      6268877     |       4.39       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I have collected the data using:
**clientside.js**

```
i1.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/createData?sensorId=0&data=0').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            m1.textContent = 'TxnHash: ' + data.sdata.transactionHash + '\n\n Gas Used: ' + data.sdata.gasUsed;
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td1.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})
i2.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/createData?sensorId=0&data=1').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            m2.textContent = 'TxnHash: ' + data.sdata.transactionHash + '\n\n Gas Used: ' + data.sdata.gasUsed;
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td2.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})
i3.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/createData?sensorId=0&data=2').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            m3.textContent = 'TxnHash: ' + data.sdata.transactionHash + '\n\n Gas Used: ' + data.sdata.gasUsed;
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td3.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})

i02.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/createData?sensorId=0&data=3').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            m02.textContent = 'TxnHash: ' + data.sdata.transactionHash + '\n\n Gas Used: ' + data.sdata.gasUsed;
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td02.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})
i05.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/createData?sensorId=0&data=4').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            m05.textContent = 'TxnHash: ' + data.sdata.transactionHash + '\n\n Gas Used: ' + data.sdata.gasUsed;
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td05.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})

d1.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/getData').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            d2.textContent = "DataID: " + data.sdata[0] + "\nSensorId: " + data.sdata[1] + "\ndata: " + data.sdata[5];
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})
```

The method calling function is like below:

```
async function asyncGetLatestData() {
    return await contract.methods.getLatestData().call();
}
```

The driver function: [web3.js](https://pastebin.com/GW2hwmM8)

Comment: Because you do not tell what blockchain you use, I assume it is Ethereum node running locally on your computer. If you want to understand this better, you can dissect both underlying Ethereum node (Go). web3.js library and JSON-RPC protocol how it behaves. However I feel making assumptions based on measurements from an environment that is supposed to be highly asynchronous and volatile in timing, does not really make sense.

Comment: I have used ropsten test chain. The driving codes are as follows:
[web3.js](https://pastebin.com/GW2hwmM8)

Comment: It does not make any sense to measure the throughput of a testnet.